# How resize images when those converted to numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, data-science, numpy-ndarray

Consider we only have images as.npy file. Is it possible to resizing images  without converting their to images (because I'm looking for a way that is fast when run the code).
for more info, I asked the way without converting to image, I have images but i don't want use those in code, because my dataset is too large and running with images is so slow, on the other hand, Im not sure which size is better for my imeges, So Im looking for a way that first convert images to npy and save .npy file and then preprocess npy file, for example resize the dimension of images.

Comment: Check out [`scipy.misc.imresize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.1/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imresize.html).

Comment: I said, "Check out [`scipy.misc.imresize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.1/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imresize.html)", but it turns out it's deprecated in favour of [`PIL`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). Give it a try - maybe it's fast enough for you.

Comment: Resizing is basically an image process - involving various forms of sampling, interpolation, smoothing and/or averaging.  `numpy` by itself does not implement most of that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try [`PIL`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), maybe it's fast enough for you.

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

arr = np.load('img.npy')
img = Image.fromarray(arr)
img.resize(size=(100, 100))
```

Note that you have to compute the aspect ratio if you want to keep it. Or you can use [`Image.thumbnail()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#create-thumbnails), which can take an antialias filter.

There's also [`scikit-image`](https://scikit-image.org/), but I suspect it's using `PIL` under the hood. It works on NumPy arrays:

```
import skimage.transform as st

st.resize(arr, (100, 100))
```

I guess the other option is [OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#cv2.resize).

Comment: Thanks for answering, But I asked the way without converting to image, I think `Image.fromarray(arr)` converts array back to image and also is grayscale, I have images but i don't want use those in code, because my dataset is too large and running with images is so slow, on the other hand, Im not sure which size is better for my imeges, So Im looking for a way that first convert images to npy and save .npy file and then preprocess npy file, for example resize the dimension of images. I don't know that's possible or not. I added this comment to above in my question for more explain others.

Comment: I didn't exam the second way, now I see in net that's returns ndarray. I'll try it, hope to give me good performance. @kwinkunks

Answer (score 1):

If you are only dealing with `numpy` arrays, I think `slicing` would be enough

Say, the shape of the loaded `numpy` array is `(m, n)` (one channel), and the target shape is `(a, b)`. Then, the stride can be `(s1, s2) = (m // a, n // b)`

So the original array can be sliced by

`new_array = old_array[::s1, ::s2]`

**EDIT**

To scale up an array is also quite straight forward if you use masks for advanced slicing. For example, the shape of the original array is `(m, n)`, and the target shape is `(a, b)`. Then, as an example

```
a, b = 300, 200
m, n = 3, 4

original = np.linspace(1, 12, 12).reshape(3, 4)
canvas = np.zeros((a, b))
(s1, s2) = (a // m, b // n) # the scalar

# the two masks  
mask_x = np.concatenate([np.ones(s1) * ind for ind in range(m)])
mask_y = np.concatenate([np.ones(s2) * ind for ind in range(n)])

# make sure the residuals are taken into account
if len(mask_x) < a: mask_x = np.concatenate([mask_x, np.ones(len(mask_x) % a) * (m - 1)])
if len(mask_y) < b: mask_y = np.concatenate([mask_y, np.ones(len(mask_y) % b) * (n - 1)])
mask_x = mask_x.astype(np.int8).tolist()
mask_y = mask_y.astype(np.int8).tolist()

canvas = original[mask_x, :]
canvas = canvas[:, mask_y]
```

Comment: This will only work with a narrow set of parameters, and won't work at all if you want to enlarge the image.

Comment: you are right, I didn't think about enlarging the image,  I have just included this part in my answer, hope this helps.